# Track Latest Merged changes

Tags: git, git-diff

Which command can be used to compare all the changes that were made with the latest git merge to the previous changes.

I have been trying to find the list of files that were changed in my latest release branch with the git merge to the origin release branch.

This is so that the tagging for only those file to be shared forward

EXAMPLE:

```
<master>
dir/file1.json
dir/file2.json
dir2/file3.json

git merge -> (Updated dir/file2.json) 

tag create 1.0-002
```

Forward only for dir/file2.json

`git --no-pager diff --name-only --relative origin/release/1.0 origin/master *.json`

Using the above command I am able to fetch all the changes between 2 branches but not able to get the changes from the latest merge on a branch to its previous version

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. Call `git diff` with 2 commits and it will show you the differences. It does not matter what, if anything, has been merged; the 2 commits will be compared directly. One or both commits can be merge commits of course.

Comment: If you have the sha of said merge commit: `git diff --name-only <sha>~ <sha>` (notice the `~`) will show you what was updated when you merged the branch. Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to see the list of changed files here are two methods.

**Method 1:**

you can use this command:

> git show --name-only --oneline [hash commit]

it will show you only the name of the files changed in the hash commit

you can use `--state` instead of `--name-only` to see more details also

**Method 2:**

if you are using vsCode , you can download `Git Graph` extension (image attached), you can see the timeline of your project and all the branches and you can expand every commit to see what are the changed files in this commit

[image: this is a picture and a small example on how it works]

Hope this could help you !

Comment: The question doesn't mention VSCode. This suggestion feels random/arbitrary.

Comment: I just suggested this method to let him visualize his changes not only on the command line, I added anw another method to see the changed files using a command :)